# Access weird JSON Format

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, api

I am using an API that returns the following JSON:

[image: Example]

I want to access the data in "value", but I have no idea how to do it. I don't want to mess around too often, because the API has a limited amount of credits and costs money.

EDIT: Sample JSON:

```
{
  "method": [
    ["somename"]
  ],
  "answer": [{
    "name": [{
      "domain": "somedomain",
      "date": "somedate",
      "value": "somenumber"
    }]
  }],
  "credits": [{
    "used": 1
  }]
}
```

EDIT2: I honestly don't get why this is being downvoted.

Comment: json.answer[0][0].value

Comment: jsonData.answer[0][0].value; gives me the error: "jsonData.answer is undefined"

Comment: What is jsonData - the top element? Additionally, give a sample json as well.

Comment: jsonData is the top element. I added a sample Json to the OP.

Comment: jsonData.answer[0]['name'][0].value

Comment: jsonData.answer[0].redactedthing[0].value gives the error: "TypeError: jsonData..answer is undefined"

Comment: Running jsonData.answer[0]['name'][0].value against your JSON example gives me 'somenumber'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get value by

```
jsonData.answer[0].name[0].value
```

Comment: Nice that worked. For some reason I first had to do var jsonData = $.parseJson("text");

Comment: Good to hear that. Additionally, If you had to do that, it means the returned text is a string and not a json object.

Comment: Yeah I figured, but it gets returned by a jQuery ajax call with dataType : 'json', so it should return json right?

Answer (score 1):

The correct path is :

```
json.answer[0].name[0].value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jsonData[1].answer[0][0].value
```

Comment: jsonData[1].answer[0][0].value  gives the error: "TypeError: jsonData[1].answer is undefined"

Comment: The root JSON element is an object. That picture is kinda misleading.

Comment: Can you assign the JSON to an object suppose jsonData.

Then try console.log(jsonData.JSON[1].answer);
If it is working fine then we will try the next step.

Comment: I had to parseJSON for some reason still. But now it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "method": [
    ["somename"]
  ],
  "answer": [{
    "name": [{
      "domain": "somedomain",
      "date": "somedate",
      "value": "somenumber"
    }]
  }],
  "credits": [{
    "used": 1
  }]
}
```

answer would be obj.answer[0].name[0].value